# Pushing objects to webservice - ForkJoinPool correct approach

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, fork-join

I have a list of objects I need to push to different webservices. I want to parallize that. Now I am wondering if ForkJoinPool is the right approach? Since the tasks are not recursive I am not sure. On the other hand I heard the performance of the ForkJoinPool is better than for example the Executor service.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to do [Task Parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_parallelism) and the FJP is a [Data Parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_parallelism) framework. But who really cares.

There are no formal restrictions on what you can/cannot do. Possibly you can just fork() different classes instead of breaking an object into fragments. If you're using Java8 then the CountedCompleter class should be a better choice than the RecursiveTask class.

Be careful with join(). In Java7 it creates continuation threads. In Java8 it tends to stall until the join() completes. Which is why I recommend the CountedCompleter class in Java8.

Try it and let us know how it works.